# How to achieve the same effect for hover in emotion?

Tags: css, emotion, css-in-js

say I have this in a css file:

```
.a-hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.a-hover:hover {
  background-color: blue;
}


.b.a-hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.b.a-hover:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

how do I achieve this in emotion?

I know I can do:

```
css`
 &:hover {
   background-color: red;
 }
`,
```

but in my specific example the hover has a different effect depending on whether it's:

- row is hovered
- individual item is hovered
- nothing is hovered

how do I achieve that?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```css
.outer{
  background:#6D8B74 !important;
}

.inner{
  background:#7D1E6A !important;
}

.outer:hover .inner{
  background:#97C4B8 !important;
}

.outer .inner:hover{
  background:#79DAE8 !important;
}

div{
  transition:all .5s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container m-3">

  <div class="row">

    <div class="card card-body p-5 outer">
     <div class="card card-body inner p-5">
     
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: That's not what OP was asking for... They didn't ask for a bootstrap version rather how to use emotionJs.